# Is there a dictionary of SFDC native interfaces we can leverage in Apex code?

Tags: apex, interface

Interfaces are wonderful for creating reusable code, as well as enabling us to reuse or make better use of the functionality SFDC already provides us.

The Apex Developer's Guide tells us how to create our own interfaces, but the Table of Contents only gives one native interface under "Interfaces" (that being Iterators).

However, I know SFDC gives us at least a few more (Batchable, Schedulable, Queueable, Iterable).

What other interfaces are available to us?  What are their intended use cases?

Answer (score 2):

So far I have gathered

- AccountCreator
- ApplicationContext
- AuthProviderPlugin
- Batchable
- BatchableContext
- Cache.CacheBuilder
- CanvasLifecycleHandler
- Comparable
- ContentDownloadHandlerFactory
- DeployCallback
- EmailTemplateSelector
- EnvironmentContext
- HttpCalloutMock
- InstallHandler
- MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator
- NotificationAction
- OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter
- Plugin
- PolicyCondition
- Process.Plugin
- Queueable
- QueueableContext
- QuickActionDefaultsHandler
- RegistrationHandler
- RenderContext
- SamlJitHandler
- SandboxPostCopy
- Schedulable
- SchedulableContext
- StubProvider
- UninstallHandler
- UrlRewriter
- WebServiceMock

Comment: Cheers for the response, but I'm actually looking more for a dictionary type list.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard list of Interface provide AFA I can check. But you can do one thing. In apex developer guide you can search for Interface and it will give you a list.

[Interface in salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm?search_text=Interface)

Here are a few for reference

- CacheBuilder
- SchedulableContext
- RenderContext
- EnvironmentContext
- CanvasLifecycleHandler
- ApplicationContext
- BatchableContext
- QuickActionDefaultsHandler
- UninstallHandler
- Plugin
- SandboxPostCopy
- DeployCallback
- StubProvider
- NotificationAction
- Schedulable
- InstallHandler
- MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator
- EmailTemplateSelector
- ContentDownloadHandlerFactory
- Queueable
- HttpCalloutMock
- AccountCreator
- Comparable
- Process.Plugin
- Batchable
- WebServiceMock

Comment: Cheers for the response, but I'm actually looking more for a dictionary type list.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKessler then you can check the link if it helps.

Comment: not really... I'm looking to actually read, not browse.  The search result box is too truncated to be useful.

Comment: @BrianKessler you can open them in new tab and then read. This is the best I can find.

Comment: Thanks, but I want something that is easier to read without navigating through multiple pages.